# Calculating cyclic values in a toroidal world

Tags: python, mathematics

```py
def eval(r, p):
    '''
    param r: robot
    param p: resampled probabilities array of particles
    '''
    sum = 0.0;
    for i in range(len(p)): # calculate mean error
        # dividing by world size ensures that toroidal world doesn't skew the resulting estimated error enclosed in 
        # the boundary
        dx = (p[i].x - r.x) + (world_size/2.0)) % world_size - (world_size/2.0)
        dy = (p[i].y - r.y) + (world_size/2.0)) % world_size - (world_size/2.0)
        err = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
        sum += err
    return sum / float(len(p))
```

This is a robot localization problem in the Udacity AI for Robotics course, section on particle filters.  The world is of size 100 *100 and `p[i].x - r.x` is the x coordinate of the particle - that of the robot) so it's an error calculation.  The world is toroidal or cyclic in Professor Thrun's words, so he adds `world_size/2.0` and then modulo `world_size` then subtracts `(world_size/2.0)` so that in his words, "so that the cyclic world does not skew the resulting estimated error enclosed in the boundary."
He gives examples of how if a robot is at 99.9 or 0.0, it should be basically next to each other but the error calculation would consider them far different without this "normalization" procedure.

The video is Lesson, number 24 in the Udacity course mentioned above.
Does anyone know how this works?  I am not that strong in math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the specific formula given is a little strange, in particular providing negative values for $dx$ and $dy$ sometimes.  I'll first provide what I think is a more straightforward version, then prove their equivalence.

Consider the circle of circumference $m$ as the set $[0, m)$, and consider two points $a, b\in[0, m)$.  The length of one of the circular arcs between $a$ and $b$ is obviously $|b-a|$, and from that the other one must be $m-|b-a|$.  Thus the distance between $a$ and $b$ along the circle is

$$\min\{|b-a|,\, m-|b-a|\}.$$

Now we just have to show that this is equivalent to the version in your code.

We have that $b-a\in (-m, m)$, and consider three cases:

- if $b-a\in (-m, -\frac m2)$: then $(b-a+\frac m2) \operatorname{\%} m = b-a+\frac{3m}{2}$, so $dx = b-a+m = -|b-a|+m$.  And this is in the range $(0, \frac m2)$, so smaller than $|b-a|$, so the minimum above works out.
- if $b-a\in (-\frac m2, \frac m2)$: then $(b-a+\frac m2) \operatorname{\%} m = b-a+\frac m2$, so $dx=b-a$.  *This is the wrong sign in the first half of the interval, but later the code squares it when computing the Euclidean distance, so it's fine.*  Similarly the minimum is OK.
- if $b-a\in (\frac m2, m)$: then $(b-a+\frac m2) \operatorname{\%} m = b-a-\frac m2$, so $dx=b-a-m=|b-a|-m$.  *This is again negative, but is taken care of when squaring.*  And again the minimum checks out.

Finally, the torus is just the product of two circles, so everything works the same for $dy$.

Answer (score 0):

That is an example of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), a system of numbers that "wrap around" when reaching a modulus value.

In this case, the modulus value is calculated by `% world_size`.